# Reading and exporting key-value pairs from a file in bash script (without caching)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, export

I have the following project directory structure:

```
myproj/
    .env
    setenv.sh
    run.sh
```

Where `run.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

sh setenv.sh

echo "$fizz"
```

Where `.env` is a properties file of `key=value` pairs like so:

```
fizz=buzz
foo=bar
color=red
```

The `setenv.sh` script needs to read the key-value pairs out of `.env` and export/source them, so that `run.sh` can reference them at runtime and they will evaluate to whatever their values are in `.env`.

The `run.sh` script and `setenv.sh` scripts need to run on Linux and/or Mac (so where `uname` is `'Linux'`, `'FreeBSD'` or `'Darwin'`) and I need to be able to run `run.sh` over and over, each time with different values in `.env`, and have them take effect on each run.

Currently my `setenv.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
unamestr=$(uname)
if [ "$unamestr" = 'Linux' ]; then
    export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs -d '\n')
elif [ "unamestr" = 'FreeBSD' ] || [ "unamestr" = 'Darwin' ]; then
    export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs -0)
fi
```

When I run `sh run.sh` it echoes the value `buzz`. But if I change `fizz` to another value, say, `buzz2`, and re-run `run.sh`, it still ouputs the `fizz` value as being `buzz`. What can I do so that the values in `.env` are always dynamically loaded/exported/sourced/etc. on each run of `run.sh`?

Comment: Have you tried `. setenv.sh` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you run `sh setenv.sh` it starts a new shell session and runs the script there. So, the new session's environment is configured, not yours.

As @Philippe suggested, you should "source" setenv.sh:

```sh
source setenv.sh # this is one way
. setenv.sh # this is another way

echo "$fizz"
```

Above code runs the content of setenv.sh in the current session, rather than in another session.